# How to fix the fetch argument error in implementing Bayesian Neural Network with tenssorflow

Tags: tensorflow

```
placeholder_X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [None, 19])
placeholder_y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [None,1])
#Build an iterator over training batches
#training_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train, y_train))
training_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((placeholder_X, placeholder_y))

#Shuffle the dataset (note shuffle argument much larger than training size).learning_rate # shuffling of data 
# and form batches of size batch_size
training_batches = training_dataset.shuffle(20000, reshuffle_each_iteration =True).repeat().batch(FLAGS.batch_size)
#training_iterator = tf.data.make_one_shot_iterator(training_batches)

#Building iterator over the heldout set with batch_size = heldout_size,
# i.e., return the entire heldout set as a constant.
val_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((placeholder_X, placeholder_y))
val_batches =  val_dataset.repeat().batch(500)
#heldout_iterator = tf.data.make_one_shot_iterator(heldout_batches)

test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_test,y_test))
test_dataset = test_dataset.batch(500)
#Combine these into a feasible iterator that can switch between training
# and validation inputs.
# Here should be minibatch increment be defined
handle = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape = [])
feedable_iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_string_handle(handle, training_batches.output_types, training_batches.output_shapes)
features_final, labels_final = feedable_iterator.get_next()

#create Reinitializable iterator for Train and Validation, one hot iterator for Test
train_val_iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(training_batches.output_types, training_batches.output_shapes)
training_iterator = train_val_iterator.make_initializer(training_batches)
val_iterator = train_val_iterator.make_initializer(val_batches)
test_iterator = test_dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()


def main(argv):
  # extract the activation function from the hyperopt spec as an attribute from the tf.nn module
  #activation = getattr(tf.nn, FLAGS.activation_function)
  # define the graph
  #with tf.Graph().as_default():

  # Building the Bayesian Neural Network
  # we are Gaussian Reparametrization Trick
  # to compute the stochastic gradients as described in the paper
  with tf.compat.v1.name_scope("bayesian_neural_net", values =[features_final]):
    neural_net = tf.keras.Sequential()
    for i in range(FLAGS.num_hidden_layers):
      layer = tfp.layers.DenseReparameterization(
          units = 10,
          activation = tf.nn.relu,
          trainable = True,
          kernel_prior_fn=tfp.layers.default_multivariate_normal_fn, # NormalDiag
          kernel_posterior_fn=tfp.layers.default_mean_field_normal_fn(),
          #kernel_posterior_fn=tfp_layers_util.default_mean_field_normal_fn(), # softplus(sigma)
          kernel_posterior_tensor_fn=lambda x: x.sample(),
          bias_prior_fn=tfp.layers.default_multivariate_normal_fn, # NormalDiag
          bias_posterior_fn=tfp.layers.default_mean_field_normal_fn(), # softplus(sigma)
          bias_posterior_tensor_fn=lambda x: x.sample()
          )
      neural_net.add(layer)
  neural_net.add(tfp.layers.DenseReparameterization(
      units=2, # one dimensional output
      activation= tf.nn.softmax, # since regression (outcome not bounded)
      trainable=True, # i.e subject to optimization
      kernel_prior_fn=tfp.layers.default_multivariate_normal_fn, # NormalDiag with hyperopt sigma
      kernel_posterior_fn=tfp.layers.default_mean_field_normal_fn(), # softplus(sigma)
      kernel_posterior_tensor_fn=lambda x: x.sample(),
      bias_prior_fn =tfp.layers.default_multivariate_normal_fn, # NormalDiag with hyperopt sigma
      bias_posterior_fn=tfp.layers.default_mean_field_normal_fn(), # softplus(sigma)
      bias_posterior_tensor_fn=lambda x: x.sample()
      ))
  logits = neural_net(features_final)
  #labels_distribution = tfd.Bernoulli(logits=logits)
  labels_distribution = tfd.Categorical(logits=logits)
  #labels_distribution = tfd.Bernoulli(logits=logits)

  # Perform KL annealing. The optimal number of annealing steps
  # depends on the dataset and architecture.
  t = tf.Variable(0.0)
  kl_regularizer = t / (FLAGS.kl_annealing * len(X_train) / FLAGS.batch_size)

  #Compute the -ELBO as the loss. The kl term is annealed from 1 to 1 over
  # the epochs specified by the kl_annealing flag.
  log_likelihood = labels_distribution.log_prob(labels_final)
  #neg_log_likelihood = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(logits,labels_final))
  neg_log_likelihood = -tf.reduce_mean(input_tensor = log_likelihood)
  kl = sum(neural_net.losses)/len(X_train) * tf.minimum(1.0, kl_regularizer)
  elbo_loss = neg_log_likelihood + kl

  # Build metrics for evaluation. Predictions are formed from single forward
  # pass of the probablisitic layers . They are cheap but noisy predictions
  predictions = tf.argmax(input = logits, axis=1)
  predictions = tf.cast(predictions, tf.float32)
  # TP, TN, FP, FN
  TP = tf.count_nonzero(predictions * labels_final)
  TN = tf.count_nonzero((predictions - 1) * (labels_final - 1))
  FP = tf.count_nonzero(predictions * (labels_final - 1))
  FN = tf.count_nonzero((predictions - 1) * labels_final)
  # precision, recall, f1
  precision = TP / (TP + FP)
  recall = TP / (TP + FN)
  f1 = 2 * precision * recall / (precision + recall)

  tpr = TP/(TP+FN)
  fpr = FP/(TP+FN)

  #create Reinitializable iterator for Train and Validation, one hot iterator for Test
  train_val_iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(training_batches.output_types, training_batches.output_shapes)
  training_iterator = train_val_iterator.make_initializer(training_batches)
  val_iterator = train_val_iterator.make_initializer(val_batches)
  test_iterator = test_dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
  with tf.compat.v1.name_scope("train"):
    train_accuracy, train_accuracy_update_op = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=labels_final,predictions =predictions)
    opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(FLAGS.learning_rate)
    train_op = opt.minimize(elbo_loss)
    update_step_op = tf.assign(t, t+1)

  with tf.compat.v1.name_scope("valid"):
    valid_accuracy, validation_accuracy_update_op = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels= labels_final,predictions = predictions)
  with tf.compat.v1.name_scope("test"):
    test_accuracy, test_accuracy_update_op = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels = labels_final,predictions = predictions)

  init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(),
                     tf.local_variables_initializer())
  saver = tf.train.Saver()

  stream_vars_valid = [ v for v in tf.local_variables() if "valid" in v.name]

  reset_valid_op = tf.variables_initializer(stream_vars_valid)

  valid_accuracy_summary = []
  stop_early =0
  with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)

    # Run the training loop
    train_val_string, test_string = sess.run([
    train_val_iterator.string_handle(),
    test_iterator.string_handle()])

    training_steps = int(round(FLAGS.epochs * (len(X_train) / FLAGS.batch_size)))

    for step in range(training_steps):
      #start reininitializable's train iterator
      sess.run(training_iterator, feed_dict = {placeholder_X:X_train, placeholder_y:y_train})
      #

      _ = sess.run([train_op,train_accuracy_update_op, update_step_op],feed_dict={handle:   train_val_string})

      # Manually print the frequency
      if step % 100 == 0:
        save_path = saver.save(sess, "/tmp/my_model.ckpt")
        loss_value, accuracy_value, kl_value = sess.run([elbo_loss, train_accuracy, kl], feed_dict= {handle:  train_val_string})
        print("Step:{:>3d} loss : {:.3f} KL: {:.3f}" .format(step , loss_value, accuracy_value, kl_value))


      if (step +1) % FLAGS.eval_freq ==0:
        # Compute log prob of heldout set by averaging draws from the model:
        # p(heldout | train) = int_model p(heldout|model) p(model|train) ~= 1/n * sum_{i=1}^n p(heldout | model_i)
        # where model_i is a draw from the posterior
        #p(model|train)
        probs = np.asarray([sess.run((labels_distribution.probs),
                                     feed_dict ={handle:  train_val_string})

                            for _ in range(FLAGS.num_monte_carlo)])
        mean_probs = np.mean(probs, axis =0).astype(np.int32)
        print(mean_probs.dtype)

        _, label_vals = sess.run((features_final, labels_final), feed_dict = {handle:   train_val_string})
        label_vals = (label_vals).astype(np.int32)

        heldout_lp = np.mean(np.log(mean_probs[np.arange(mean_probs.shape[0]), label_vals]))


        print(" ...Held_out nats: {:.3f}".format(heldout_lp))

       # Calculate validation accuracy

        for step in range(10):
          #start reinitializable's validation iterator
          sess.run(val_iterator, feed_dict = {placeholder_X:X_val, placeholder_y:y_val})
          sess.run(validation_accuracy_update_op, feed_dict={handle:train_val_string})

        valid_value = sess.run(valid_accuracy, feed_dict={handle:train_val_string})

        valid_accuracy_summary.append(valid_value)
        if valid_value < max(valid_accuracy_summary) and step > 100:
          stop_early += 1
          if stop_early == 40:
            break
        else:
          stop_early = 0
        print("Validation Accuracy: {:.3f}".format(valid_value))
        sess.run(reset_valid_op)

        #Feed to r=feedable iterator the string handle

        test_value, precision_value, recall_value, fpr_value, tpr_value,f1 = sess.run([test_accuracy, precision, recall, fpr, tpr,f1],feed_dict={handle:  test_string})

        print("Step: {:>3d} test Accuracy: {:.3f} Precision: {:.3f} Recall: {:.3f} ".format(step, test_value, precision_value, recall_value))

        print("Step: {:>3d} fpr: {:.3f} tpr: {:.3f} f1_1: {:.3f}".format( step, fpr_value, tpr_value,f1))




if __name__ == "__main__":
  tf.compat.v1.app.run()
```

Expect the output to progress but it is giving out this error

```
Step:  0 loss : 0.646 KL: 0.875
Step:100 loss : 0.654 KL: 0.904
Step:200 loss : 0.657 KL: 0.906
Step:300 loss : 0.648 KL: 0.906
int32
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:137: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
 ...Held_out nats: -inf
Validation Accuracy: 0.914
Step:   9 test Accuracy: 0.000 Precision: 0.910 Recall: 1.000
Step:   9 fpr: 0.099 tpr: 1.000 f1_1: 0.953
Step:400 loss : 0.624 KL: 0.906
Step:500 loss : 0.641 KL: 0.906
Step:600 loss : 0.612 KL: 0.906
Step:700 loss : 0.579 KL: 0.906
int32
 ...Held_out nats: -inf
Validation Accuracy: 0.914
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in __init__(self, fetches, contraction_fn)
    302         self._unique_fetches.append(ops.get_default_graph().as_graph_element(
--> 303             fetch, allow_tensor=True, allow_operation=True))
    304       except TypeError as e:

14 frames
TypeError: Can not convert a float64 into a Tensor or Operation.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in __init__(self, fetches, contraction_fn)
    305         raise TypeError('Fetch argument %r has invalid type %r, '
    306                         'must be a string or Tensor. (%s)' %
--> 307                         (fetch, type(fetch), str(e)))
    308       except ValueError as e:
    309         raise ValueError('Fetch argument %r cannot be interpreted as a '
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception arises because you use same name f1 as assignment, we need to change name f1 at left side.

```
   test_value, precision_value, recall_value, fpr_value, tpr_value,f1 = sess.run([test_accuracy, precision, recall, fpr, tpr,f1],feed_dict={handle:  test_string})
```

change the line to

```
test_value, precision_value, recall_value, fpr_value, tpr_value,f1_value = sess.run([test_accuracy, precision, recall, fpr, tpr,f1],feed_dict={handle:  test_string})
```

Hopefully, this will work.